# GitHub pull request without forking

Tags: version-control, git, github

Is it possible to submit a pull request if I originally cloned a repo locally rather than using the GitHub "fork" functionality??

The scenario is that I have created a local clone of a repository and made some changes. I would like to submit these back via pull request. I can create a repo on GitHub and push my changes there. Once I do that, will I be able to use the "new pull request" functionality, or will GitHub be unable to recognise that the repo is equivalent to a fork?

Comment: see [Where does my tool question go?](https://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/where-does-my-tool-question-go)

Comment: Why not fork and then push the changes? Creating a separate repository just wastes your (and GitHub) bandwidth as well as (probably) storage space (forking could use hard links)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter *when* you create the fork because of the distributed nature of git, but github needs a fork in order to make the association necessary to create a pull request, and it also lets people searching your profile more easily make the association back to the original project.  Without the fork, you break a lot of very helpful links.

In my local workspace, I usually like to set up one remote called `upstream` to more easily pull from the original, then have `origin` point to my fork.  After you create a fork, you can use the instructions [here](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/) to change your `origin` remote url, then just push to there like normal.  That way you won't lose any of your existing history.

Comment: cat `~/bin/hub-fork`:

    `hub fork $*;`
    `git remote rename origin up &&`
      `git remote rename $USER origin;`
    `git remote -v`

Comment: This isn't 100% accurate - Even GitHub's own UI states that you can "Compare and review just about anything", when you create a new pull request.